# Simple XML Load File with PHP

Tags: xml, parsing, simplexml

i have problem when parsing XML with simplexml_load_file method. I have xml like this one:

```
<root>
    <show>
        <list>
            <entry name="this is title" code="1234">
                <infos count="4">
                    <info type="random" percent="10" />
                    <info type="random" percent="12" />
                    <info type="random" percent="13" />
                    <info type="random" percent="15" />
                </infos>
            </entry>
            <entry name="this is titles" code="1235">
                <infos count="4">
                    <info type="random" percent="14" />
                    <info type="random" percent="16" />
                    <info type="random" percent="17" />
                    <info type="random" percent="18" />
                </infos>
            </entry>
        </list>
    </show>
</root>
```

And i trying parsing with simplexml_load_file, but i just get one result. Not two entry, i mean. Look at this code below.

```
<?php
$url = "text.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->show->list as $entry) {
$name = $entry->entry['name'];
$code = $entry->entry['code'];

echo "<p>The List Name: ".$name."</p>";
echo "<p>Code:".$code."</p>";
}
?>
```

Okay, i try with that code, and i just get one result. I didn't know how to loop. So, i trying to ask in this site.

1. How to loop the result exactly as the xml.
2. Parsing XML with

Thanks for everybody who can give their hand :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($xml->list->enrty as $entry) {
    $name = $entry->entry['name'];
    $code = $entry->entry['code'];

    echo "<p>The List Name: ".$name."</p>";
    echo "<p>Code:".$code."</p>";
}
```

Should be

```
foreach ($xml->show->list->entry as $entry) {
    $name = $entry->attributes()->name;
    $code = $entry->attributes()->code;
    //or like this
    //$name = $entry["name"];
    //$name = $entry["code"];
    echo "<p>The List Name: ".$name."</p>";
    echo "<p>Code:".$code."</p>";
}
```

Comment: yeah, it's work, but just show one entry. how to show all of the rest entry?

Comment: `$xml->show->list->entry`  Dont forget `->show->`    http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/xaf-ecu